# Can the prerequisite for RCM ARCT Piano (Performer) fulfilled through ABRSM certificates?

Tags: exam-grades, exam

I have the [ABRSM](https://www.abrsm.org/en-gb/instruments/piano) Grade 8 Piano and Theory certificates from more than 10 years ago.  Can I use this to fulfill the prerequisite to take the RCM ARCT Piano Performer exam, or do I have to *first* obtain the similar [RCM Level 10 Piano comprehensive certificate](https://www.rcmusic.com/learning/examinations/recognizing-achievement/recognizing-achievement-canada#ComprehensiveCertificatesRequirements-6), according to page 100 of the [2022 Piano syllabus](https://rcmusic-kentico-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/rcm/media/main/about%20us/rcm%20publishing/piano-syllabus-2022-edition.pdf) before attempting the ARCT Performer exam?

The pre-requisite is also mentioned in the [list of Examinations Required for the ARCT Performer Diploma](https://www.rcmusic.com/learning/examinations/recognizing-achievement/arct-lrcm).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why switch to RCM rather than go for an ABRSM diploma?

Comment: @Aaron Because I'm now in Canada, and RCM is a lot more recognized here, and I want to eventually get their RCM Teacher certificate.  I'm planning to contact them (after they come back from holidays), and when I got the answer, I'll post it here for future visitors.

Comment: I thought that boards diversified at that level - and *teacher* was a different syllabus from *performer*.  You say you want to go on to the *teacher* but ask about *performer*. Why would you need both?

Comment: @Tim You're right that they have ARCT in Piano Pedagogy diploma that has their own 3-tier track (see syllabus [here](https://rcmusic-kentico-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/rcm/media/main/documents/examinations/syllabi/rcm-piano-pedagogy-2016_online_(secured).pdf)).  It seems to be RCM Teacher certified RCM provides multiple options, see [Rubric here](https://rcmusic-kentico-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/rcm/media/main/teaching/documents/rubric-_p-t.pdf).  Both have their advantages.  I think for the first step, since I have never been to an RCM exam, the ARCT Performer would be the low hanging fruit for me.

Comment: @Tim I can also take their [Online Piano Teacher Courses](https://www.rcmusic.com/teaching/online-piano-teacher) to be RCM Certified Teacher, with fewer requirement of submitting successful student exams (only 2 instead of 10).  But then I also want to brush up my own piano skills and the ARCT Performer seems to be a good goal for me in 2024 or 2025.

Comment: It may depend on what you want to do, but in U.K., I taught for many years and was never asked for qualifications - experience and reputation I suppose was enough. But that was privately, up to higher than grade VIII (diploma) level (which I only did on piano, not guitar, bass or theory, my mainstays). It was the same in bands - never was asked what grade I achieved  - I was either good enough at the audition - or not!

Comment: @Tim That sounds right.  In my profession (IT), especially at the senior level, experience counts a lot more than a university degree.  I'm doing music primarily as a hobby and wanting to advance classical music appreciation among the young (including my own children), so I may look into Piano Pedagogy more to prepare myself.  The ARCT Performer motivation is to get ready into participating in chamber music and becoming a professional accompanist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RCM allows for the transfer of theory credits from ABRSM, but not performance. Here's the core of my communication with RCM.

> Thank you for your message. According to the [Theory Equivalents Table](https://files.rcmusic.com//sites/default/files/examinations/documents/forms/Theory%20Equivalents_Prerequisites%20and%20Corequisites_Oct2017.pdf) on our [Forms and Services](https://www.rcmusic.com/learning/examinations/forms-and-services#TransferCredits-5) page, ABRSM Grade 8 Theory is equivalent to Level 9 Harmony; if you wish to transfer that credit, please fill out the form found on our Forms and Services page.
>
> Unfortunately we do not have Practical Exam exemptions; you will be required to take all practical examinations required for the ARCT Piano Performer Diploma. For more information on the requirements for this diploma, please visit our website [here](https://www.rcmusic.com/learning/examinations/recognizing-achievement/arct-lrcm).

Comment: Thank you for contacting them. You beat me to it :-). Maybe I'll take ABRSM performance diploma instead, and the RCM Piano Pedagogy separately. But since I have to take ARCT Harmony & Counterpoint, ARCT History, and ARCT Analysis (good for review anyway), I may end up still taking ARCT Performer's.

Comment: But you haven't quite answered my question though, it's about the prerequisite *prior* to taking the ARCT Performer exam, which I want to take regardless.  So the question is: can I take the ARCT practical exam right away, or do I still have to take the Level 10 practical exam first, which doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: There are no substitutes for the practical exam, so, yes, you would have to take it. "You will be required to take all practical examinations required for the ARCT Piano Performer Diploma."

Comment: I will take the practical ARCT piano exam, however the question is whether I need to take the level 10 piano exam *first*, thus 2 practical exams instead of just the more advanced one.  I have emailed them with a pointed question.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Yes, you have to take the level 10 exam first. It's listed in the prerequisites for the ARCT exam: "Level 10 Comprehensive Certificate (in the same discipline as the ARCT Performer) with a minimum overall practical mark of 75% or a minimum of 70% in each section of the Level 10 practical examination"

Comment: Yes, that's what the text says, and they emailed me back saying the same thing, but I'm appealing (since I had some upper division music major college credits).  I also noticed that ARCT performer turns out to be only repertoire.  The ARCT exams themselves [are already expensive](https://www.rcmusic.com/learning/examinations/examination-resources-for-students/examination-and-other-service-fees-canada), so I don't want to take any Level 10 exams only as a prerequisite, unless it's absolutely necessary .  We'll see what they say.  Or I may re-evaluate whether I should pursue this.

Comment: Got a response.  Basically unless I want to apply for special exception and supply tons of info, including college course outline and college transcript (for theory), and additional proofs including college jury exam (for performance), the Level 10 Comprehensive certificate requirement still stands :-(.